# How to create own toolbox in Sci Lab

Tags: scilab

I have Scilab code related my Ph.D Work, Now i want to create a toolbox so that it could be work in Scilab platform. My code contain the one .sce file(Main program) and several .sci files(Sub routines called in main program). Is it Possible to create toolbox which can be used later in other programs (like Command Syntax).
Just like Ex: print,disp,etc..

Answer (score 1):

See the instructions in the Scilab Wiki : https://wiki.scilab.org/howto/Create%20a%20toolbox